# Amperage of HP DL140 G1

Tags: windows-server-2003, electrical-power

How many amperes DL140 G1 Dual Xeon 3.06 with 2 IDE disks normally consumes at 240V ?

Need to calculate colocation costs.

**My reading : DL140 G1 Dual Xeon 3.06 with 2 IDE disks consumes 1.7A for me, in my scenario**

Comment: If idle, I would guess around 100-150 watts.

Comment: thank you. anyone has real-life experience? I need to calculate costs with actual figure.

Comment: This is an *old* server.  Are you sure you want to colo an old slow server with a pair of old, slow disks?

Comment: yes I am....... I mean - if you willing to donate couple of hundreds I can buy Dell R210 any time. thank you

Comment: @Bobb grab an ammeter... every configuration will be a little different -- number of RAM sticks, type of drives, etc.

Comment: I downvoted the question because I believe it is too localized. If this was for professional use, you could phone up HP and ask them. Also since there are tons of configuration possibilities and multiple hardware combination this question is just silly. The only way you will get actual 'real life' results is by just buying yourself an AMP meter, plug in the server and benchmark it.

Comment: yeah. ammeter costs around 20 quid. I need +/- 0.1A not exact figure obviously.

Answer (score 5):

Well the PSU is rated at a steady-state power of 325W with a maximum peak power of 420W.

Now this is a maximum, obviously load is based on how hard you're working the box and you don't mention what country/voltage you're in but if you're using a 120v input then that's 3.5 Amps and if it's a 220-240v input then that's 1.75-1.9 Amps.

Comment: the question states 240V. I am looking for zero-load power consumption figure. thanks

Comment: This site aims to not just answer the immediate question but to provide good data to help others if they ever find this question via search in the future, hence why many of the higher-rep users on this site sometimes 'over-answer'. And a literal zero-load would obviously draw nearly zero Amps, but I assume you mean nominal-load (i.e. just the OS running, no actual serving) in which case assume a 25-33% of max draw.